# Cleaner props comparison in shouldComponentUpdate

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

When using Immutable.js, I noticed that when you make an array immutable, all of the elements array becomes part of the immutable object such that if you change one of the elements, all of the elements will be considered new, which of course, will trigger a rerendering of all of the elements in the array, which is bad.

```
const taskList = [
{
    name: 'task 1',
    priority: '1',
    isDone: false

},
{
    name: 'task 2',
    priority: '1',
    isDone: false

},
{
    name: 'task 3',
    priority: '1',
    isDone: false

}
];

var tl = Immutable.fromJS(taskList);
```

However, I realized that the properties of the element themselves aren't immutable so in the component level you can implement a shouldComponentUpdate method like this that compares all of the properties of the elements.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {

    return (this.state !== nextState || this.props.name !== nextProps.name || this.props.priority !== nextProps.priority || this.props.isDone !== nextProps.isDone  );
}
```

I tested it and it works, but this code isn't clean and it's not easy to maintain, so I was wondering if there was a cleaner implementation that was possible.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {

    return (this.state !== nextState || this.props !== nextProps );
}
```

In case you didn't read, the above doesn't work, because of the reason mentioned above.

```
toggleTask(task) {
    const found = _.find(this.state.taskList, task => task.name === task);
    found.isDone = !found.isDone;
    this.setState({ taskList: this.state.taskList });
}
```

EDIT: I heard that using lodash with Immutable.js may be redundant, but I am not sure which lodash methods insure correct "mutability" if that makes any sense.

Comment: It would be useful to see code of 1) how you define immutable object from array. 2) how you "change one of the elements" and 3) how you bind this object to the props of the React component.

Comment: "all of the elements array becomes part of the immutable object such that if you change one of the elements, all of the elements will be considered new" -- This assumption is faulty, or how you changed the element is faulty. Only the reference of the array and the element that has changed should be different.

Comment: when I compare this.state and nextState, I get true no matter what. Both are arrays with props.